# How to prevent GUIs picking up an outdated version of PHP

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP project with Composer. The project runs in Docker which has PHP 7.4.

On my system, I also have MAMP and I've put a symlink into my ~/bin which is in my $PATH so that when I do `php` in the terminal, MAMP's PHP 7.4 runs.

The project's git repository has a git hook which runs on commit.

When I do a git commit on the terminal, everything works fine.

But if I git commit from a GUI, I get this message:

> Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.4.0". You are running 7.3.11. in /PROJECT/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24

I have used Homebrew to upgrade the MacOS system PHP, and doing this confirms the version:

```
$ sudo -i
Password:
root# php --version
PHP 7.4.25 (cli) (built: Oct 21 2021 07:30:24) ( NTS )
```

The PHP version warning happens with Gitx, VSCode, but not GitUp.

Where are these GUIs managing to find a wrong version of PHP?

Comment: [You can manually point to PHP within VS Code.](https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/languages/php/php-settings.png) Have you tried that?

Comment: That's set to my ~/bin/php. The issue I think is the way in which VSCode is invoking git, which then causes git to run a mystery version of PHP!